# Directory structure management for PHP script

Tags: php, directory-structure

I'm writing a profile-based image downloader, and it's structured in multiple files:

```
lib/
profiles/
getbooru
install
readme
uninstall
```

If I include these files like this:

```
include 'lib/curl';
include 'lib/string';
foreach(glob('profiles/*') as $profile)
    include $profile;
```

The program only works if you call it from the program's directory. If I change it to this:

```
set_include_path('/usr/local/share/getbooru');
include 'lib/curl';
include 'lib/string';
foreach(glob('/usr/local/share/getbooru/profiles/*') as $profile)
    include $profile;
```

Then it forces the users to run an install script to put the files in that directory, and it won't work anywhere else. In this case, `getbooru` is symlinked to `/usr/local/bin/getbooru`.

**Good news:** I noticed that if I try to get the filename of the running script, even if it's running through a symlink, it'll always return the 'real' script name (so that I don't include nonexistent stuff from `/usr/local/bin`).

How can I make this program portable to run anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__));
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach I've seen is to grab the base path from a configure script and store it in the apps config file, e.g. `global $base_path; $base_path='/var/www/myapp/';`.  Then you include like this `global $base_path; include $base_path.'lib/curl';`. You have to be careful to include the config file before you do any other includes.